# Java HashSet equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, lookup

I was curious if there was something akin the Java HashSet in C++? I.e. a data structure with a fast look, as I will only be running `.contains(e)` on it. Likewise, if you could enlighten me on how to do a `.contains()` on whatever data structure you propose, I would be very appreciative. O, please do not post just look at the c++ docs as I have already done so and found them burdensome.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` would be the closest

Answer (score 20):

You can use `std::unordered_set<>` (standard § 23.5.6), its [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) method (to do a lookup) as an average complexity of O(1)  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{  
    std::unordered_set<int> example = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    auto search = example.find(2);
    if(search != example.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found " << (*search) << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @Drew Dormann, you can alternatively use [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count), which also has a average complexity of O(1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
{  
    std::unordered_set<int> example = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    if(example.count(2)) {
        std::cout << "Found\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `count()` for emulating contains().  That 2 line if becomes simply `if(example.count(2))`

Comment: The function was named `count()` to be consistent with multisets, but for `unordered_set` it will only return `1 (true)` or `0 (false)`